# Correct syntax for malloc without specifying type of variable

Tags: c, malloc

I have seen on the web the following syntax to use `malloc` :

```
double ***x;
x = malloc(N * sizeof(*x));
for (i = 0; i < size_y; i++) {
   x[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(**x));
```

i.e, the type of variable which is pointed, is not specified into `malloc` : usually, we declare pointer like this :

```
double ***x;
x = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
for (i = 0; i < size_y; i++) {
   x[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(double**));
```

From what I have understood, the first method allows to quickly changing the type pointed just by replacing the "`double ***x`" by "`int ***x`" for example.

In the second method, we have to replace all "`double`" by "`int`" into `sizeof`

Is this first method valid and if yes, is it recommended?

Comment: There's a slight mistake in the code you show, it should be `sizeof *x` in the first `malloc` call and `sizeof **x` in the second.

Comment: It's really a matter of taste. `x = malloc(N * sizeof(double**));` is more explicit on what you are allocating (here pointer to pointer to double). On the other hand, `x = malloc(N * sizeof(**x));` will not change if you decide to use `long double` of `float` instead of double. Both method are valid and none is more recommended than the other - except by local rules in a project or in an organization

Comment: Oh, and being called a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is usually *not* a compliment.

Comment: sorry, I had a confusion

Comment: Your question shows a lack of understanding for some basics about declarations, `sizof` and what `malloc` actually is used for. These are all basics required to understand C programs and which are taught in every C book. Please find a good one and work through the chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it valid?*  Yes (in principle).  The `sizeof` operator can apply to a type (as in your second example), or equally it can apply to any expression (returning the size of the type returned by that expression).  So it is valid.  I say "in principle" because you are passing the wrong expression to the wrong `malloc` call, though.

*Is it recommended?*  Well, I would recommend it for the reasons you've already stated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the first method. It aligns with [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principles and allows you to easily see that the memory allocated is the correct size.